# FIX CSS <!--[if lt IE 8]> in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

How can I use this:

> ```
>     <!--[if lt IE 8]>
>     <style type='text/css'>
>   #header ul#h-menu li a{font-weight:normal!important}
>     </style>
>     <![endif]-->
> ```

If I remove `<!--[if lt IE 8]><![endif]-->`, above code'll run good in IE 8, but if I don't do it, it wont run.
Help me with fixed IE, so that I can use above code in all IE versions.

I want the code `#header ul#h-menu li a{font-weight:normal!important}` to run only in IE.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Whatever style will be in your conditional statement will run in all IE version lower then IE 8. But I'm not sure what you want, that code won't have any effect in IE 8 as it targets all browser lower then IE 8. Coulde you please explain what exactly you want?

Comment: i want code #header ul#h-menu li a{font-weight:normal!important} run only in IE

Comment: nice javascript way to detect the IE version of your browser at [this link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want this to work in IE 8 and below, use

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
```

`lte` meaning "Less than or equal".

For more on conditional comments, see e.g. the [quirksmode.org page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: And it might be a good practice to only put a reference to an external stylesheet in your conditional comment. Better readability in my opinion.

Comment: @Justus: And better cacheability along with smaller HTML source code, too.

Answer (score 27):

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><![endif]-->
```

The lt in the above statement means less than, so 'if less than IE 8'.

For all versions of IE you can just use

```
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
```

or for all versions above ie 6 for example.

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]><![endif]-->
```

Where gt is 'greater than'

If you would like to write specific styles for versions below and including IE8 you can write

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]-->
```

where lte is 'less than and equal' to

Answer (score 6):

`[if lt IE 8]` means "if lower than IE8" - and thats why it isn't working in IE8.

wahat you want is `[if lte IE 8]` which means "if lower than or equal IE8".

Answer (score 6):

Use `<!-- [if lt IE 9] >` exact this code for IE9.The spaces are very Important.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
<!--[if IE]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

You can read [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) about conditional comments.

Comment: this will work because it will trigger all versions of IE. However you may prefer to use the `lte IE 8` version because you may not want it running in IE9.

Comment: OP asked for "only in IE", without further specification. Otherwise, yes, the `lte IE8` would be most surely better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type='text/css'>
    #header ul#h-menu li a{font-weight:normal!important}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

will apply that style in all versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the comment tag

```
<comment></comment>
```

is only supported in IE 8 and below, so if that's exactly what you're trying to target, you could wrap them in comment tag. They're the same as

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]-->
```

In which lte means "less than or equal to".

See: [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
I found cascading it works great for multibrowser detection.
```

This code was used to change a fade to show/hide in ie 8 7 6.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 8.0)
         { 
             $(".glow").hide();
            $('#shop').hover(function() {
        $(".glow").show();
    }, function() {
        $(".glow").hide();
    });
         }
         else
         { if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 7.0)
         { 
             $(".glow").hide();
            $('#shop').hover(function() {
        $(".glow").show();
    }, function() {
        $(".glow").hide();
    });
         }
         else
         {if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 1) == 6.0)
         { 
             $(".glow").hide();
            $('#shop').hover(function() {
        $(".glow").show();
    }, function() {
        $(".glow").hide();
    });
         }
         else
         { $('#shop').hover(function() {
        $(".glow").stop(true).fadeTo("400ms", 1);
    }, function() {
        $(".glow").stop(true).fadeTo("400ms", 0.2);});
         }
         }
         }
       });
```