# Browser Conditional CSS Stylesheets

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Im trying to use conditional stylesheets to target different versions of IE.

I have the following

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="_includes/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<link href="_includes/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="_includes/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Which works okay, but in IE8 it seems to pickup ie6.css and I cant for the life of me figure out why. Has anybody any idea?

Thanks

---

Ive also used

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
```

with no luck

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835485/css-for-ie-8-only

Comment: "Has anybody any idea?" No, it can't be… But another hint: `if IE 7` and `if gte IE 7` both includes ie7.css, so its doubled somehow;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lte` means **less than or equal to**, therefore you probably want:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link href="_includes/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

I'd guess it's possible IE 8 is identifying as IE 7 because it's in compatibility mode. Check your `DOCTYPE` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh I figured it out!

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
```