# ExtJS DateField rendered too wide, bug in IE8?

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm stuck on a bug that I can't seem to find a solution for. In IE8 the Date Field component is being rendered too wide (outside the default 200 which is set in PHP and the delegate). All other browsers and new IE versions render it fine. Which is `183px` for the field, and `17px` for the calendar trigger. But in IE8 the field is being rendered as `199px` which results in pushing the calendar trigger below since the entire field has `200px` max width.

[image: Bug in IE8]

ExtJS version is 4.0.5, FYI.

And idea why this is occurring? Any help would be appreciated. Google and Sencha forums have not been much help.

Here is where we're creating the date field instance:

```
this.DateComponent = Ext.create(this.GetEXTJSClass(),Object.extend(this.GetConfigProperties(), {
    id: this._Type+'_'+this.FieldName,
    value: this.SelectedDate,
    disabledDays: this.DisallowWeekends,
    width: aOptions.width || 200,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: aOptions.renderTo || this.ID,
    format: this.DayBeforeMonth ? "d/m/Y" : "m/d/Y",
    showToday: this.ShowToday,
    allowableYears: this.GetAllowableYears(),
    validateOnBlur: false,
    todayText: this.TodayText,      // not supported configuration option, passed through overridden createPicker method
    listeners: this.GetListeners()
}));
```

**EDIT**
As a side note, I thought perhaps we might be overriding the CSS in some custom file and after checking -- that is not the case. Also, since IE9-11 as well as FF, Chrome, Safari all render it properly.. I have a strong suspicion that this is either an IE8 bug or something we are doing is not being supported in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend overriding changing the css class for IE8 to work around this issue:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
 //Add your css file here ie: ie8.css
<![endif]-->
```

You can find addtional help here:

[CSS for IE 8 Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835485/css-for-ie-8-only)

Comment: I was hoping to find the cause, not a hacky solution. Targeting for IE8 specifically will be my last resort :-/