# Blogger IF IE not working

Tags: internet-explorer, blogger

```
 <[if !IE]><style>#content-slider {display: none;}</style><[endif]>
```

I cannot get this to work for the life of me. 
How exactly can I get this to work in a Blogger template?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358716/ie-conditional-comments-need-explaination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358716/ie-conditional-comments-need-explaination) and answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3958950/3105260](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3958950/3105260) a d [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) is a good limk suggested in another answer.

Comment: @iokanuon do you have a blog on Blogger? Because I already tried it that way and it didn't work. Thank you for the quick response though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this coding instead of the above because it looks that `<[if !IE]>` creates a wrong mean in html. However, I've already tried this one below and it works for me:

`<!--[if IE]> <script>` your java script here `</script> <![endif]-->`